# EXCEL VBA - Transferring data from multiple workbooks to workbook template

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make an excel ui/macros which allows the user to select multiple excel workbooks(wb1,wb2,wb3...) and transfer certain values from them to another workbook(wb_template). Afterwards, saving each one of them as new workbooks (wb1_new,wb2_new,wb3_new...).

**Meaning:** The template workbook can be used over and over again, and is being saved as a new workbook every time - should be named after the original workbook(wb1) + "_new"):

```
>     Wb1 + wb_template = wb1_new
>     Wb2 + wb_template = wb2_new
>     Wb3 + wb_template = wb3_new
```

To summarize the scenario:

- Selection of multiple workbooks via dialog box
- Displaying the selection in a list box
- Transferring certain values from those workbooks into a workbook template
- Saving the workbook template as a new workbook for each excel workbook from the list box
- **Result**: a couple of new excel workbooks, named after the original excel workbooks from the list box

How can I achieve something like this? Here is a screenshot of the current UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXPap.jpg

**I have this code for the data transfer:**

```
Sub Button1_Click()


Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb_template As Workbook

Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\PlutoX\Desktop\Folder\wb1")
Set wb_template = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\PlutoX\Desktop\Folder\wb_template")


wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value



wb1.Close False
wb_template.Close True


End Sub
```

**Problems:**

- Origin files(wb1) are static. Need a variable that refers to the selected files from the list box - adding the filepaths of the selected files to the code

**I have this code for the dialog window/selection of files:**

```
Sub openDialog()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd

      .AllowMultiSelect = True

      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select the file."

      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
        txtFileName = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox

      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

**Problems:**

- How do I display the file names in the list box? Can't figure it out...
- How do I make sure that the filepaths are handed over to the variable from the "data transfer" code?

Would be very grateful for some help!

Answer (score 0):

For the first, I'd say abandon the `FileDialog` and use Excels built-in method. Something like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fNames As Variant
    With Me
        fNames = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel File(s) (*.xls*),*.xls*", , , , True)
        If IsArray(fNames) Then .ListBox1.List = fNames
    End With
End Sub
```

Above goes to your `BrowseFile` (from screen shot) button.
For the `Transfer File` button, you need to iterate to the `ListBox` items.
But before that, you need to make your file transferring `Sub` generic. Something like:

```
Sub Transferfile(wbTempPath As String, wbTargetPath As String)

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb_template As Workbook

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(wbTargetPath)
    Set wb_template = Workbooks.Open(wbTempPath)

    '/* I believe this should be dynamic but that is another story */
    wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value

    wb1.Close False
    wb_template.Close True

End Sub
```

Above is a `Sub` procedure taking on 2 arguments.
Now, the remaining part is the code for the `Transfer File` button which should look like something:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()    
    Dim i As Integer
    '/* I assumed it is fixed, note that you need the full path */
    Const mytemplate As String = "C:\Users\PlutoX\Desktop\Folder\wb_template.xlsx"
    With Me
        With .ListBox1
            '/* iterate listbox items */
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                '/* transfer the files using your generic procedure */
                Transferfile mytemplate, .List(i, 0)
            Next
        End With
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I get an error message when try to compile the code - **"data object/method cant be found"** --it points me to the "ListBox1" in the code. What am I mssing? Just to be sure: 

**1)** The browse file button gets the "Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()" code
**2)** The Tranfer Data Button gets the "Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() " and the "Sub Transferfil" code? Is this correct?
**3)** What do I have to do with the ListBox? Shouldn't the ListBox be somehow connected to the rest?

Comment: @PlutoX You need to add a `Listbox` control where you display the selected files as seen in your screen shot. The `Transferfile` procedure should sit in the same `Userform` module where your 2 command button procedures are.

Comment: Omg it works! Thank you so much for this! I just got one more question: how do I save the `wb_template` as  a new file every time? I need to create a new workbook for every workbook (wb1,wb2,wb3..) of the `listbox`. Because right now my wb_template is getting overwritten every time....what I need is that my wb_template is being reused all the time to get the data from `wb1` and to save it as a new workbook - `wb1_new`. Then to get the data from `wb2` and create a new workbook again - `wb2_new`...ans so on. Thats all I need - would appreciate your help @L42   ! :)

Comment: To be more precise -  I need a loop for every workbook in the `listbox`. For example:  Copy data from `wb1` to `wb_template` and save the `wb_template` *as a new file* named after the *original file(wb1) + name extansion (_new)*. Then repeat the process for every workbook left in the `listbox`(wb2, wb3...etc).

Comment: So, after the process I should have a newly created excel file for every workbook from the list, and they should be named after the original file name(wb1,wb2 or wb3) + a name extansion ("_new). So something like this: **"wb1_new"**.

Comment: any idea how to do this?

Comment: Yes. You will have to create the filename and have it dynamic. Please post a separate question for that. Include a reference in this question everyone will know the back ground.